# How to get DataXML from Slide Diagram in Powerpoint using Apache POI

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi, powerpoint, openxml

I have added one smart art shape in the Microsoft power point presentation slide.
I want to get the data of that diagram in Java using apache POI.

How to retrieve the complete data.xml from first slide of presentation.
I opened the presentation and following is the hierarchy of presentation.

[image]

I want to **retrieve the data from first slide smart art diagram in XML** ( complete data1.xml )

Following is the code for getting first slide i have developed so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String filename = "resources/fptbenchmark/Powerpoint Import.pptx";

    try {
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream(filename));
        ppt.getSlides()[0]. //here first slide
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know you'll always want `/ppt/diagrams/data1.xml`, then your code would want to continue with:

```
OPCPackage pkg = ppt.getPackage();
PackagePart data1 = pkg.getPart(
       PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/ppt/diagrams/data1.xml"));
InputStream data1Inp = data1.getInputStream();
```

Then pass that InputStream to your XML parsing code to process

If you need to find the part dynamically based on the slide, you'll want to check the Relationships defined on your Slide part, and go from there

Comment: thank you , can you tell me how to replace the xml file , i tried with data1.getOutputStream().write but the presentation isnt changing the file XML

Comment: Is PowerPoint caching the data elsewhere? Getting the part output stream + writing in + saving the package should be all that's needed if not

Comment: can you please provide me some helpful material for generating my own data.xml for smart art diagram. in java ?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I'd suggest you ask a brand new question for that, and include some sample XML you want yours to be based on in that

Comment: sure i have posted new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704532/how-to-generate-dataxml-in-openxml-for-powerpoint-in-java